# ionic2 with stripe payment gateway

Tags: angular, stripe-payments, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I am trying to create an application in ionic 2 by embedding stripe payment gateway. I have included com.telerik.stripe plugin. On trying to display the console log on app initialization, window.stripe remains undefined and i am getting error as "Property 'stripe' does not exist on type 'Window'". Is there any tutorial to embed stripe with ionic 2 application. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide more information and code that explains what you have tried, where you failed and if possible, an error message.

Comment: Some code that demonstrates what you tried would be great. Please check the help menu about how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution to make stripe to work in ionic2. The solution is to run "ionic build " after adding the plugin. Once done, displaying console log as "stripe" under platform ready event defines the stripe in my project. :)